# One-to-many relationship in django - how to force the parent to have at least one child

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have two models, artwork thats store information about an art piece and media who store information about the media atached to the art piece, in summary an artwork can have one(not zero) or many medias and a media only can belong to an artwork.

My problem is that I can't do that django force artwork to have at least one media before to be created and I'm not sure about how to work around this, maybe changing the manager?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you can just override artworks save() method, and in there, check if has a relation with a media object. If not, don't create the new artwork record

Comment: can you please share both the models?